# Have view object number in oracle?

Tags: oracle, view, synonym

Have view object number ?
Have view segment ? 
Have synonym object number ?

So I know dictionary view dba_,all_,user_objects, in this view have object_id column and is this counted object number of view or synonym and etc. which have types of object in the object_type column?  And I know that view is query and not segment but need help in all for accuracy and sorry my english bad.. In some cases I cannot find clear answer in some questions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views and synonyms are objects, so they have an object number, but a view does not consume physical space in the database, so it does not have a segment

```
SQL> create or replace view V as select * from dual;

View created.

SQL> create synonym SYN for V;

Synonym created.

SQL> select object_id, object_name
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name in ('V','SYN');

 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME
---------- ----------------------------------------
     73166 SYN
     73165 V

SQL>
SQL> select * from user_segments
  2  where segment_name = 'V';

no rows selected
```

Comment: Mr. @ConnorMcDonald can you help me in some questions via email ?

Comment: Best to use asktom.oracle.com or stackoverflow so that the entire community can benefit